# postgreSql and Rails order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

Using PostgreSQL on my Rails application but rails method Order is not working.

```
    @comments=@album.comments.order("created_at DESC")
```

It gives me the same results as

```
     @comments=@album.comments.order("created_at ASC")
```

Using MySQL it's working but in PostgreSQL not working, I am using Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Hmm. That is strange. Please, check ending SQL-queries which you get from Ruby-code: `logger.info @album.comments.order("created_at DESC").to_sql` (look for logged SQL in log/development.log, or in the server console)

Comment: This code *should* work fine, as Sergey says we need to see the queries which they generate.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

`@comments = @album.comments.order(:created_at)` for ascending order

`@comments = @album.comments.order(:created_at).reverse_order` for descending order

Comment: why do the work in Ruby when it can be done much more easily at the database level?

Comment: @sevenseacat: it occasionally make senses when if the DB is not collated properly.